# ios table cell left detail not dynamic size

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have a storyboard with a static table view.

It has a cell that is a counter.  It is a left detail :

countLabel         "Records"

I update the countLabel when my count increases, however some thing really weird happens when the count gets to double digits, ie 10.  The label only diplays 1.  Meaning I see the count increase from 1 - 9, then when count hits ten the label only displays the first digit.

I update it like this:

```
NSUInteger count = [self getCount];
[countLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count]];
```

I tried to make the label bigger in the story board but it does not seem possible.  Am I supposed to do something else to dynamically increase the size of the label. Have no idea why it is disappearing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you Joined the Table view Delegates

Comment: what do you have in getCount?

Comment: Try to call sizeToFit in countLabel after updating the text

Comment: sizeToFit worked, thanks.  Do you always need to do that when the size of a label field grows?  Should I not be using a label field for a dynamic number?

Answer (score -1):

Increase countLabel width.And check by setting background color of countLabel that how much label is displaying.

```
    NSUInteger count = [self getCount];
    [countLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count]];
    [countLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

If it is showing label area after printing 1 then there could be some other issue.But if it is not showing Label Area after 1 then there is issue of width of count Label(Increase count Label width).

If not yet solved then use below code:-----

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateLbl) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)updateLbl
{
    count++;
    [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count]];
    CGSize lblSize = [lbl.text sizeWithFont:lbl.font];
    [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(lbl.frame.origin.x,lbl.frame.origin.y,lblSize.width,lblSize.height)];
}
```

Comment: Yes it is a size problem as sizeTofit does work.  Again however seems like I should be able to make this label big enough in the storyboard such that I do not need to keep resizing it.

Comment: yes, but sometimes I update the count once per second.  Seems over kill to constantly adjust the size.  Seems like I should be able to set a max size once in the storyboard.

Comment: I don't want to resize at all.  Is that possible?  I want to set then label to a max width and leave it there.